# Facebook connect plugin is not working in android but working in ios

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

i have a plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0"> <param name="APP_ID" value="998855950166112" /> 
<param name="APP_NAME" value="abc" /> 
</gap:plugin>
```

This plugin is for fb connected i have issue that its working on ios but not in android. i have search in phonegap repository and and also in npm repository but i didn't get. is this issue for not updating plugin.code is perfect because its works fine on ios. i have search update of plugin but didn't get it. give me guidance for finding update of plugin i am new bee in phonegap so i didn't get any.

Answer (score 1):

That plugin is deprecate. This is the 5th time tonight. Don't you guys check your sources.

I am posting this link with the hope you will read the entire document.

[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

In fact your error was

**11. You need to get your plugins from NPM now.**

How did I figure this out? I did a google search of your plugin: [com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect](https://www.google.com/search?q=com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect)

About three (3) links down is your plugin: [FacebookConnect](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect)

The documentation says

### REPOSITORY IS NOW DEPRECATED!!!

#### Please go [here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

READ THE DIRECTIONS CAREFULLY. This is an ugly plugin. The correct links are:

- [github](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando)

Your new plugin setting is:

`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando" source="npm" version="0.11.0">`

Comment: i have replaced my old plugin with your new plugin <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando" source="npm" version="0.11.0"> after that i have got plugin build error like Oh geez. Your build failed. Sorry, but a problem occurred on the build server. but when i remove your's suggested plugin my build is sucess but facebook connect is not working on android phone.

Comment: Okay. There is something else broken. Please post your `config.xml` to some public website, like github.com or pastebin.com. In addition, please add to your original post (the bottom is best), your target platforms (iOS9, Android, etc.)

Comment: My config file you can see on this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053190/splash-screen-is-not-display-after-build-on-phonegap-version-cli-5-2-0 Or on this Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383326/phonegap-build-error-failed

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 In andriod Phone there is already installed facebook app install i have removed it and try to login with facbook i am sucessfully login. Authentication works.. if am using plugin <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0"> <param name="APP_ID" value="998855950166112" /> 
<param name="APP_NAME" value="abc" /> 
</gap:plugin> so is it problem with facbook app.

Comment: **Deprecated** means: (computing) Obsolescent; said of a construct in a computing language considered old, and planned to be phased out, but still available for use. -- There is a new plugin (0.11.0). it should work with your app. If it is not working with the new plugin, I have to ask have you implemented the `whitelist`. If not, your app will be reject by Google and iTunes.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650  I have alread implemented whitelist. this is i below mention  gain :- <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" source="npm"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>  but having still issue if i updated as your given.

Comment: Sorry, I though I had given you this link. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md) The default `whitelist` is NOT enough, especially if you use iOS9. This will help too: [whitelist worksheet](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md) I'll be up for few hours. It is 9:40pm (MST, USA)

Comment: @jesseMonroy This issue in android happen when in phone facebook native app is already installed if i remove facebook app and try to login with facebook i am succesfully login.so i didn't get any clue what problem  having with facebook native app is installed.

Comment: Wait? I don't undestand. I think you said you have a "facebook app" and "your app". When you remove "facebook app", "your app" works. Your English is not good. Please use https://translate.google.com/

Comment: @jesseMonroy I want to say in android Phone if Facebook Native app is already install than in my phongap build app facbook authebtication is not working.. if i remove facebook native app from my phone and try facebook authentication in my phongap build app its works fine.

Comment: Okay. Now we are clear. Please use translate.google.com more. Your issue is a BUG we must report. We have been having this bug for weeks. Some people have found a solution, some not. It appears you have found the bug. Please go to http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi  - I will work to get this bug escalated. I'm not sure if we can fix this. I am on that forum also.

Comment: @jessemonroy i have already posted there my bug link is  

 http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/facebook-connect-plugin-is-not-working-in-android-while-having-facebook-native-app-is-install-but-working-in-ios?rfm=1.

Comment: Great. I saw that. I am following it.