# Phonegap Build Error failed

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Oh geez. Your build failed. Sorry, but a problem occurred on the build server. Having this issue from last 2 days. is any way to build app i am using phongap cli 5.2.0. my ios & android app is not gone be build whats problem must going on. i didn't understand. if any one have other way to Build app please provide me. 
by uploading zip and its provide us build like that.my config file is below mention.

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.abc.mobileapp" version="1.0.0" versionCode = "10">
  <name>abc</name>
  <description></description>
  <author email="admin@abc.com">abc</author>
  <content src="abc.html"/>
  <preference name='phonegap-version' value="cli-5.2.0"/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <!--<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />-->
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
  <!--<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="6000" />-->

  <!--<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>-->
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" source="plugins.cordova.io" />

  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"  version="0.2.12" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" version="0.3.11" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando" source="npm" version="0.11.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="0000000000000000" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="abc" />
  </gap:plugin>

  <!-- Third party plugins -->
  <!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
  <!--<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />-->

  <!--https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/2fdfde7/README.md
  <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.toast" version="2.0.2" />-->

  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>

  <gap:splash src="res/screen/default.png" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <!--<access origin="*xitstage-001-site3.mysitepanel.net"/>-->
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" source="npm"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: awfull late reply, but I wonder: what does the phonegap build log say? I had similar problems including the inAppBrowser plugin for iOS, the log pointed me that this was the problem.