# phonegap build error in ios and android with the facebook-phonegap-plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Up until now i used this:

```
   <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
        <param name="APP_ID"   value="******" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="******" />
    </gap:plugin>
```

This plugin is depreceted, in here ([Facebook connect plugin is not working in android but working in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338686/facebook-connect-plugin-is-not-working-in-android-but-working-in-ios/33338844#33338844)) im being told to use this instead:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando" source="npm" version="0.11.0">
    <param name="APP_ID"   value="****" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="****" />
</gap:plugin>
```

But with this i have errors in both ios and android builds, why?

This is my config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="blah.blah.com"  version="0.9.1" >
    <name>blah</name>
    <description>
        Best football manager in a long time
    </description>
    <author email="gorgo@gorgo" href="http://www.gorgogorgo.com/">
       gorgo
    </author>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.2.0' />
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="screen-orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />


     <icon src="icon.png" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
    <icon src="icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

    <!-- Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />

    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />

    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    </platform>

    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="fr-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xxhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-xxhdpi" />


    <gap:splash src="Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

     <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-667h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <gap:splash src="Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

     <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" overwrite="true">
        <false/>
    </gap:config-file>


    <!-- phonegap build plugins from npm, secured -->
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" source="npm">
      <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="footboss" />
    </gap:plugin>

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" version="1.0.0" />

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"  version="0.2.12" source="npm" /> <!-- being used in push notifications service -->

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4" source="npm"/> <!-- working good -->


    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
        <param name="APP_ID"   value="***" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="***" />
    </gap:plugin>

    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.insomnia" version="4.0.1" />

    <gap:plugin name="at.modalogb2.cordova.plugin.cache" version="1.0.0" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.lowlatencyaudio" version="1.1.3" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.5.0" />

    <gap:plugin name="net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation" version="1.3.1" />

    <gap:plugin name="net.bgta.phonegap.plugin.appversion" version="1.1.1" />

    <!--<gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.gaplugin"/>-->
    <gap:plugin name="com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics" version="0.6.1" />

    <gap:platform name="ios" />
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <gap:platform name="winphone" />

    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>

    <allow-navigation href="*" />

    <allow-intent href="*" />


</widget>
```

This is the build fail from the phonegap build:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/Footboss.build/Release-iphoneos/Footboss.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FacebookConnectPlugin.o Footboss/Plugins/cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando/FacebookConnectPlugin.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Should this be solved by adding to the plist something?

Answer (score 0):

To Start, You have multiple plugins you need to source from NPM

[PhoneGap 5.2.0 Now Available on Build](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/23/phonegap_520_now_on_build/) - 23 Sep 2015

**I Quote:**

> Also make sure your third party plugins all are up-to-date, and that your  core plugins are being sourced from NPM, like so:
>
> `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" />`
>
> If you’re updating from pre-5.1.1, read this [blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/).

For instance

`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"  version="0.2.12" source="npm" />`

Should be:

`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" version="1.0.1" />`

This work sheet for core plugins should help.

#### Core Plugins Setup

https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-setup.md

Comment: But the problem is the facebook login plugin, not everyone else

Comment: Your post says your **BUILD Failed**. So, if your build is working, you need to change your post or decide what you want to do. Because at this point, I am only trying to get your build to work. OHHH. and please list your target platforms. Almost all PLUGINS have quirks.

Comment: It also says why it failed, if the older (not very good now) plugin is used, build is ok, but if i put the new and needed facebook plugin! it fails on ios and android... i was very specific even in the heading.

Comment: I don't think you want to fix this problem. There are three people that are on this forum that can help you. Petra V. at nitobi, jcesarmobile which is on both forums. I am the third. You DID NOT make this stupid situation, and i DID NOT make this stupid situation, I'm only trying to get you out of it. Make the change. I'm not going anywhere unless you want to try Petra or Jcesarmobile. If the latter, wait for an answer on nitobi.

Comment: i really appreciate what your doing, really, i made the changes just as you said, for the other plugins, building now, hope it helps...

Comment: I'll keep checking. This may turn into a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95414/discussion-between-totothegreat-and-jessemonroy650).